# Progress Dialog setContentView not working in onCreateDialog DialogFragment

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-dialogfragment, android-progressbar

I am using this code for showing `Progressbar` according to my need :

```
public class DelayedProgressDialog extends  DialogFragment
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setCancelable(false);
    }



    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
          ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.setTitle(null);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout._task);
        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:indeterminateTint="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now issue is that my custom progressbar not showing in this fragment when I call this:
showing normal progressbar on left side without title, I want to show in centre.  and if I removed setContentview then not getting any effect which means my custom view not showing in this, how can I show my view inside this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a basic dialog, for example `Dialog` class and then set the content view you designed in layout (which seems correct). Since you are using a ProgressDialog, it could be interfering with your `ProgressBar` widget defined in your layout.

Here is how you can do it:

```
@Override 
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.setTitle(null);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout._task);
    dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    return dialog;
}
```

Also, you could try with a Dialog instead of DialogFragment:

```
public void showProgressDialog() { 
   Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
   dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
   dialog.setTitle(null);
   dialog.setContentView(R.layout._task);
   dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
   dialog.show();
}
```